# Merge two Field Sets and use them in VF

Tags: fieldsets

I want to create a very dynamic VF page with custom controller which would change field sets based on my custom logic.

The real question is - can I create new Field Set in apex that would be then used in VF?

If so - how?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you asking?  The title or the question? (PS - Either way, I like the quesiton)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a new `Field Set` in Apex, but you can merge Sets. If you are not familiar with how to get the collections of `Schema.FieldSetMember` you need, [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) is a good tutorial.

```
public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> set1Members { get; private set; }
public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> set2Members { get; private set; }
// You can write these getters!

public Set<String> set1Fields
{
    get
    {
        if (set1Fields == null)
        {
            set1Fields = new Set<String>();
            for (Schema.FieldSetMember field : set1Members)
            {
                set1Fields.add(field.getFieldPath());
            }
        }
        return set1Fields;
    }
    private set;
}

public Set<String> set2Fields
{
    get
    {
        if (set2Fields == null)
        {
            set2Fields = new Set<String>();
            for (Schema.FieldSetMember field : set2Members)
            {
                set2Fields.add(field.getFieldPath());
            }
        }
        return set2Fields;
    }
    private set;
}
```

Now just combine them:

```
public Set<String> allFields
{
    get
    {
        if (allFields== null)
        {
            allFields = new Set<String>();
            allFields.addAll(set1Fields);
            allFields.addAll(set2Fields);
        }
        return allFields;
    }
    private set;
}
public List<String> displayFields
{
    get
    {
        return new List<String> ( allFields );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this gives me a list of fields from a field set... which is useful, but it does not make it a field set that I can use in the VF page.

Comment: You can absolutely use this in VF, just cast it back to a list. You haven't really enumerated which properties of a `Field Set` you want to maintain,  but if you're clever you can do pretty much all of it with strings.

Comment: How would you 'cast it back'?

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely edit metadata through Apex.  Check out the [apex-mdapi project](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/) from FinancialForce for an example.  However, this sounds like something that might be beyond the use of FieldSets and something closer to just using very dynamic VF (possibly in combination with Hierarchical Custom Settings to store your personalized settings).  If you can expand on the question (the end goal of your page, perhaps), I'd be able to point you in the right direction.